# Unable to sync Geth on testnet -- "potential rewrite attack"

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ropsten

I'm trying to do a fast sync on testnet and when I'm a few thousand blocks from the end it get's caught up in "potential rewrite attack" and the sync craws to a standstill. Retried a few times.

From what I read this happens because it's connecting to peers on another chain. How can I fix this? Really need to get the Ropsten blockchain up and running.

This is on Geth 1.5.5

```
I0109 12:28:25.240911 core/blockchain.go:1042] imported 1 blocks,     1 txs (  0.068 Mg) in   7.873ms ( 8.676 Mg/s). #307220 [2be43506…]
I0109 12:28:50.384733 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 8c5ef4d490aa810b [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 16.242456742s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:30:43.874138 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 2243f34584f582c2 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:30:51.981788 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 34282ad7b29591ab [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:31:05.643768 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 17ddc3eb0ac57a21 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:31:18.876271 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 0cbd61469dce5c4b [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:31:30.268372 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 8779e82b7fe6ea55 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:33:41.239244 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer b3e5e884df039c61 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
I0109 12:33:45.293838 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer d40bfe9758cfb344 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #217220 [00000000…] <= #217220 limit
```